# Passing List of object to view from conroller, but how to access it in view cell by cell

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to access a specfic cell value at the view, if we have passed the table from database as a list to the view already in asp.net mvc ?

Comment: What do you mean "as a list"? A single table column? Can you show your code?

Comment: @Tibin, we need more information on this. Are you passing a List<T> object to your view in a model, and you're trying to access it in your cshtml page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that you have a table named **Students** in your database.
Your controller method should look something like this :

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        var list = context.Students.ToList();
        return View(list);
    }
}
```

And here are 3 examples on how to access the list model with Razor in your view :

```
@model List<Students>

@Model[0].FirstName // Displays the Firstname of the student in position 0 in the list 

// This foreach loop displays all the students Firstname
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item.FirstName
}

// Same as above but with for loop
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <p> @Model[i].FirstName </p>
}
```

Comment: Where do you have this error ?  
This was provided as an example, could you provide some code to help us there ? @TibinThomas

Comment: Thanks.... It works...Sorry for the poorly crafted question.

Comment: No problem ;) Mark this as the answer if it helped you.